# How to print the filename with parent directory in insert mode?

Tags: insert-mode, filesystem

I know that I can print whole path by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd> `expand('%:p')` in insert mode. I can also print head/tail with `expand('%:h')`, `expand('%:t')`.

I want to print the filename with it's parent directory. Like if the full path was 
`/home/torsho/maalamaal/src/maalamaal/urls.py` it would insert `maalamaal/urls.py`

Comment: Do you actually want the filename and exactly one parent directory, or do you want the path relative to the `src/` directory?

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple modifiers in a single call to expand, so you can find the parent directory by asking for the tail of the head.

Therefore, you can use:

```
expand('%:h:t') . '/' . expand('%:t')
```

If you need to do this frequently, you could perhaps use a mapping so you don't have to type it in all the time:

```
inoremap <F5> <C-R>=expand('%:h:t') . '/' . expand('%:t')<CR>
```

If you want it to use a backslash as the path separator on Windows, you can check the operating system with `has()`:

```
inoremap <F5> <C-R>=expand('%:h:t') . (has('win32') ? '\' : '/') . expand('%:t')<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [`:h filename-modifiers`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#filename-modifiers)
for a list of the modifiers you can use with `expand()`. A possible solution is the following:

```
expand('%:p:s?.*/\(.*/\)/?\1?')
```

It uses the full path modifier `:p` and then the substitution modifier `:s` to keep only the last directory in the path and the filename + extension.